# EvaluateJavascript() won't execute

Tags: javascript, swift, webkit, swift4, wkwebview

I am using swift 4 for this project. I am trying to use the EvaluateJavascript() function to run javascript on a webpage running in a WKWebView. I am trying a simple alert function to start to make sure the javascript is executed. The javascript won't execute. I searched several Stack Overflow questions and none of them work for this.

Here is what I did so far:

I created a new Xcode project and created a WKWebView. I linked it to the code. Here is the code:

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webtest: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let urltest = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        webtest.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
        webtest.evaluateJavaScript("alert(1);") 


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try yo load le page and evaluate the script on viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad?

Or set webview delegate and check when the page has been loaded and then run the script

Comment: I tried running the script after the page has loaded by creating a button that I click when the page is loaded. I don’t think the issue is with the page loading.

Comment: look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170736/wkwebview-evaluatejavascript-not-returning-html/43172313), you have to implements WKScriptMessageHandler