# iOS WebKit - Determine whether a WebView has completely loaded JS content

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit

I'm attempting to parse out some HTML metadata from a third-party URL; however, I don't get the full HTML data until some Javascript scripts are executed in the `WKWebView`.

So I've been trying to detect when the `WKWebView` has completely loaded the web page with Javascript but unfortunately I wasn't able to.

Here's what I tried:

- I tried using `WKUserContentController` and handled the protocol method but that didn't work because the protocol method is only executed when it receives a script message not when it's completed.
- I tried adding an observer for `WKWebView`'s `estimatedProgress` but `estimatedProgress` return 1.0 before JS scripts are done loading.
- I tried using `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol method `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` but it's essentially the same thing as adding an observer.
- I also tried using `WKWebView`'s `evaluateJavaScript` method in the `observeValue` method to check both:

  - `document.readyState == \"interactive\"`
  - `document.readyState == \"completed\"`

but that didn't work either because it's executed way before JS is done loading.

**Code**

Here's the code of the last approach I attempted and didn't work:

**Initializing the `WKWebView`**

```
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .new, context: nil)
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

**Handling the observer**

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
        if let webView = object as? WKWebView, webView.estimatedProgress > 0.5 {
            print(webView.estimatedProgress)
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState == \"interactive\"") { (isLoaded, err) in
                print(isLoaded)
                if let loaded = isLoaded as? Bool, loaded == true {
                    print("completely done loading with JS")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result I get when the `evaluateJavaScript` method is executed is `false` because it's executed too early. But I'm trying to let the observer continue until `isLoaded` is true.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your WKWebView has loaded:

```
import WebKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

  let webView = WKWebView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.yourwebsite.com/") !
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(request)
  }

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStart navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Strat to load")
}

  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     print("loaded")
     //It will print "loaded" in the console everytime the WKWebView has finished loading the page. 
  }
}
```

But it is per each resource, not for the whole page with all the resources. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43172313/3857830

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer my questions for 2 main reasons. 

1. I'm not using `UIWebView`, I'm using `WKWebView`
2. I have already tried a similar protocol method provided in `navigationDelegate` but the method is executed way before the JS scripts are complete.