# How to read the html of a website when the typical javascript commands return nil?

Tags: javascript, html, swift, wkwebview

None of the ways I've found to read the body of the html are working, all are returning nil.

```swift
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ProjectGetJSONJasper
//
//  Created by Scott Lydon on 5/1/22.
//

import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: WKWebViewController {

    override var startWebsite: String {
        "https://app.jasper.ai/?_gl=1%2a1r3ye0c%2a_ga%2aMjA2NDczMDkwNy4xNjUxMDI3NjMx%2a_ga_D4P3CS8W5P%2aMTY1MTM4NjA0My43LjEuMTY1MTM4NjA1MS41Mg.."
    }
}


class WKWebViewController: UIViewController {

    var startWebsite: String {
        "overide me!"
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        setupViews()
    }


     func setupViews() {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self

        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(webView)

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: startWebsite)!))

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [
                webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            ]
        )
    }

    @objc func evaluated(_ webView: WKWebView, html: String, error: Error?) {
        // override me!
    }
}

extension WKWebViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()") { [weak self]
            (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
            guard let html = html else { return }
            self?.evaluated(webView, html: String(describing: html), error: error)
        }
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML") { [weak self]
            (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
            guard let html = html else { return }
            self?.evaluated(webView, html: String(describing: html), error: error)
        }
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML") { [weak self]
            (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
            guard let html = html else { return }
            self?.evaluated(webView, html: String(describing: html), error: error)
        }
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document") { [weak self]
            (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
            guard let html = html else { return }
            self?.evaluated(webView, html: String(describing: html), error: error)
        }
    }
}

extension WKWebViewController: WKUIDelegate {

    // So alerts and popups appear to be intercepted and available for my control through delegate methods!
    // It can also be a way to print or send information to myself from the webpge.  This confirms that my javascript was executed!!!! woot woot!
    func webView(
        _ webView: WKWebView,
        runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
        initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo
    ) async {
        print("reached: ", message)
        print("bla")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked [this]) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170736/wkwebview-evaluatejavascript-not-returning-html) ?

Comment: To the linked question, it’s unrelated because my evaluatejavascript is getting called back, however, the answers offer some ways to get better responses.  I will explore those! Thank you.